# Invalid XML Character During Unmarshall

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am marshalling objects to XML file using encoding "UTF-8". It generates file successfully. But when I try to unmarshal it back, there is an error:

> An invalid XML character (Unicode:
>   0x{2}) was found in the value of
>   attribute "{1}" and element is "0"

The character is 0x1A or \u001a, which is valid in UTF-8 but illegal in XML. Marshaller in JAXB allows writing this character into XML file, but Unmarshaller cannot parse it back. I tried to use another encoding (UTF-16, ASCII, etc) but still error.

The common solution is to remove/replace this invalid character before XML parsing. But if we need this character back, how to get the original character after unmarshalling?

---

While looking for this solution, I want to replace the invalid characters with a substitute character (for example dot = ".") before unmarshalling.

I have created this class:

```
public class InvalidXMLCharacterFilterReader extends FilterReader {

    public static final char substitute = '.'; 

    public InvalidXMLCharacterFilterReader(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {

        int read = super.read(cbuf, off, len);

        if (read == -1)
            return -1;

        for (int readPos = off; readPos < off + read; readPos++) {
            if(!isValid(cbuf[readPos])) {
                   cbuf[readPos] = substitute;
            }
        }

        return readPos - off + 1; 
    }

    public boolean isValid(char c) {
        if((c == 0x9)
                || (c == 0xA) 
                || (c == 0xD) 
                || ((c >= 0x20) && (c <= 0xD7FF)) 
                || ((c >= 0xE000) && (c <= 0xFFFD)) 
                || ((c >= 0x10000) && (c <= 0x10FFFF)))
        {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
 }
```

Then this is how I read and unmarshall the file:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(this.getFile());
Reader reader = new InvalidXMLCharacterFilterReader(fileReader);
Object o = (Object)um.unmarshal(reader);
```

Somehow the reader does not replace invalid characters with the character I want. It results a wrong XML data which can't be unmarshalled. Is there something wrong with my InvalidXMLCharacterFilterReader class?

Comment: Could you please check in XML header, which charset is defined in it after marshalling? Is it UTF-8?

Comment: There is no charset defined in XML header, only <?xml version="1.0" ?>. But I have put this: `m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Can someone explain why the "read()" method above does not just return the variable "read"?

Answer (score 3):

I think the main problem is about **escaping illegal characters during marshalling**. Something similar was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435934/problem-with-escape-characters-in-jaxb-marshaller), you could try it out.

It offers to change encoding to Unicode `marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "Unicode");`

Comment: I tried to escape illegal characters during marshalling as mentioned there, which is transforming character "0x1a" into character reference "$#x1a;" and changed the encoding into "Unicode", but I still got an error during unmarshalling: _Character reference "&#x1A" is an invalid XML character._

Answer (score 3):

The Unicode character U+001A is [illegal in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets):

The encoding used to represent it does not matter in this case, it's simply not allowed in XML content.

[XML 1.1 allows some of the restricted characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets) (including U+001A) to be included, but they **must** be present as numeric character references (`&#x1a;`)

Wikipedia has [a nice summary of the situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Valid_characters).

Comment: Do you know how to set Marshaller property to have XML 1.1 header? I tried this one but it did not work: `m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.1\"?>");`

Comment: It looks like JAXB doesn't support XML 1.1 yet: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-422

Comment: I don't think the offending character is 0x02, note the curly braces around {2} and {1}, this looks more like the placeholders in the error message did not get replaced.

Comment: @Jörn: you're right, U+001A seems to be the problem, but that character has the same problem.

Comment: Can it be treated by using another XML Serialization API?

Comment: @oliverwood: as long as the other API supports producing XML 1.1: yes.