# How to prevent Java from changing "&" to "&amp;" in XML file

Tags: java, xml, string, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I need to build a XML file using Java. The problem is I have to use some special characters like "ć" and then read it in my mobile apps.

It works fine if I manually change `<tag>ć</tag>` to `<tag>&#263;</tag>` in Notepad in my XML file. But when I try doing it in java, for example using:

```
result = result.replaceAll("ć", "&#263;");
```

I get something like `<tag>&amp;#263;</tag>`which results in wrong display in my client application.

How can I do it to just replace `ć` with `&#263;`without any parsing?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to explicitly escape. Java's APIs for XML should do this implicitly. Anyway, does this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435934/problem-with-escape-characters-in-jaxb-marshaller) come close to answering yours?

Comment: if `<tag>&amp;#263;</tag>` in an XML file results in wrong display, the fault is at the client application, and should be fixed there

Comment: if `ć` needs escaping, java xml api does it implicitly, no need for any alternative todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. I don't know if there is a way to do what you're doing without parsing. Because & is a special character in XML you have to either escape it or wrap the content of the element in a CDATA block so it wont be parsed by the XML parser.

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class AsciiTesting {

    @Test
    public void parse() {
        final String myString = "ćabc123ć";
        System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("ć", "&#263;"));
        // Then wrap the <tag> content with <![CDATA[ put your replaced string here ]]>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Java XML APIs take care of escaping characters as needed by the output encoding of the file, so you should not perform any replacement of 'special characters' from your code.

Comment: But when I don't do anything, I get just "ć" in my final XML, which result to display weird characters instead, eg. "Ä" on my application.

Comment: That may be a problem in the application that reads the XML, not the one writing it...

Comment: I don't know, but I know, when I change 'ć' to '&#263' manually in notepad, it works fine. I just want Java not to do anything for me :)

Comment: @michalsol: Farrandu is correct. Java is doing its job correctly. The problem is in the application that is reading the XML, not in the application is that creating the XML. `ć` is encoded as `0xC4 0x87` in UTF-8 (XML's default charset). 0xC4 is `Ä` when interpretted as ISO-8859-1 (and 0x87 is `‡`). The reading application is ignoring the XML's true encoding and is interpreting the XML's raw bytes using the wrong charset. You need to fix *THAT* bug in your reading application. There is nothing wrong with the XML itself, it is being encoded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get to touch the raw markup when you're working with an XML serialiser. The whole purpose of XML tools is so that you can write plain text content and not have to worry about using the right form of escaping.

The correct thing to do is to leave `ć` where it is and let the serialiser write it into the appropriate encoding, hopefully UTF-8 as this is the default and only sensible encoding for XML files. Note: do not trust what the output looks like in Notepad. Notepad is a hopeless editor that defaults to a useless locale-specific encoding instead. Use a better editor such as Notepad++ that will show you what encoding it is using to display a file and let you change it.

If you see `ć` in the file and the editor tells you it read the file as UTF-8, but the mobile apps still won't read it correctly, then those apps are broken and should be fixed.

If you can't fix them and have to work around it for now, the best thing is to tell your XML serialiser to write to the ASCII encoding instead of UTF-8. Since ASCII can't directly accommodate characters like `ć`, so the serialiser will encode to `&#263;` to compensate. How you set the encoding varies depending on what you're using to produce XML; for example for a `Transformer` you might `setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "US-ASCII");`.