# How to display '&' inside XML generated via Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: xml, spring

Can someone guide me to generate XML using Jaxb2Marshaller with special characters e.g. '&', '<', '>'? I have got a few pointers on StackOverflow to use below snippet in spring config file, but the same doesnt work out & I continue to receive '&amp', '&lt', '&gt' respectively. Any pointers will be really helpful.

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
<property name="marshallerProperties">
    <map>
        <entry key="jaxb.encoding">
            <value>UTF-8</value>
        </entry>
    </map>
```

Comment: Could you provide example of generated value and desired value?

Comment: Generated Value: <name> Test &amp; Value </name>;   Desired Value: <name> Test & Value </name>

Answer (score 0):

&<> may not appear inside valid XML. they must be either changed to named entities (&<>) or present inside CDATA block. Sample you provided

```
<name> Test & Value </name>
```

Is not valid XML!
It must be either

```
<name> Test &amp; Value </name>
or
<name><![CDATA[Test & Value]]</name>
```

This answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/4438368/1849837 shows that you could use  EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy). It has annotation @XmlCDATA, that you could add to your element.

Comment: Thanks Bartosz! I tried via CDATA using below class (as an adapter to to Jaxb2Marshaller), but it returns encoded data inside CDATA (&amp); how can that be escaped?:   `public class StringCustomAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> { public String unmarshal(String fieldValue) throws Exception { return fieldValue; } public String marshal(String fieldValue) throws Exception { fieldValue = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml("<![CDATA[" + fieldValue + "]]>"); return fieldValue; } }`