# Java Unescaping XML/HTML before JAXB parsing doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, unicode, jaxb

Can anyone help me?

**In HTML/XML:**
A numeric character reference refers to a character by its Universal Character Set/Unicode code point, and uses the format:

**&#nnnn;**
or
**&#x hhhh;**

I have to unescape (convert to unicode) these references before I use the JAXB parser.

When I use Apache StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml() also **&amp ;** and **&gt ;** and **&lt ;** are unescaped, and that is not want I want because then parsing will fail.

Is there a library that only converts the &#nnnn to unicode? But does not unescape the rest?

**Example:** 
**begin-tag** Adam &lt ;&gt ; Sl.meer 4 & 5 &# 55357;&# 56900; **end-tag**

I have added spaces after &# otherwise you do not see the notation.

For now I fixed it like this, but I want to use a better solution.

```
String unEncapedString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(xmlData).replaceAll("&", "&amp;")
                .replaceAll("<>", "&lt;&gt;");
StringReader reader = new StringReader(unEncapedString.codePoints().filter(c -> isValidXMLChar(c))
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString());
return (Xxxx) createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(reader);
```

**Looked in the Apache Commons-text library and finally found the solution:**

```
NumericEntityUnescaper numericEntityUnescaper = new NumericEntityUnescaper(
                    NumericEntityUnescaper.OPTION.semiColonRequired);
xmlData = numericEntityUnescaper.translate(xmlData);
```

Comment: could you provide a sample of the xml you are trying to unmarshal?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435934 ? Why does [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435934) not work for you? Did you set `marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "Unicode");` ?

Comment: I know but this is unmarshalling

Comment: Caused by: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: jaxb.encoding value: Unicode

Comment: unmarshalling doesn't recognize that option. And &#nnnnn or &#xhhhh isn't unicode notation but HTML/XML escaped smileys etc.