# JAXB Multiline Attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

IS there a way to marshall/unmarshall xml/object multiline attributes .

Currently it is showing as

```
<task name="Payament Gateway
Checker" >
```

It would be best , if store it by replacing nextline whitespace with \n ?

```
<task name="Payament Gateway \n Checker" >
```

**Edit** -

Tried Both Adapter and JaxbListener - but converted to name="Payament Gateway &#xA; Checker"

```
void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller) {
 name = name.replaceAll("\n", "&#xA;");    
 }
```

---

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MultilineString.class)
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String name;

public class MultilineString extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String marshal(String input) throws Exception {
        return input.replaceAll("\n", "&#xA;");
    }
    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String output) throws Exception {
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

JAXB should be replacing the Java `\n` with `&#xA;` which is the proper XML escaping.  If you are not seeing this then there may be a bug in the version of the JAXB implementation you are using.  For example this issue was fixed in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) in version 2.5.1:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/414608

---

### Example

**Java Model (Foo)**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo Code**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("Hello\nWorld");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo bar="Hello&#xA;World"/>
```

---

### Workaround

You can always use an `XmlAdapter` to control any output in JAXB.

Comment: `void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller) {
        name = name.replaceAll("\n", "&#xA;");//converted to name="Hello &amp;#xA; World"
}`

Comment: Tried both JaxbListener and Adapter but results to `&amp;#xA;` .

Comment: @userG - You can use the `com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler` property to override the default escaping: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6933922/383861